# inserting data into mysql using PDO, returns error HY093

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

im really blurry eyed when coding, and cant seem to find out whats causing `HY093` error that i get from inserting data to mysql using PDO

```
function whatever($post_id, $comment) {
...
$query = "INSERT INTO `comments` (`id`, `post_id`, `comment`) VALUES (:id, post_id,:comment)";
$sql = $db->prepare($query);
$check = $sql->execute(array(':id'=>'',
                             ':post_id'=>$post_id,
                             ':comment'=>$comment));

//verify if data is inserted
if($check) {
    $test = 'inserted';
} else {
    $test = $sql->errorCode();
}
    return $test;
}
```

i get this error `HY093`.

my `id` is auto-increment, im not sure if using `''` is the correct way of declaring it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot a `:` before `post_id`

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `comments` (`id`, `post_id`, `comment`) 
          VALUES (:id, :post_id, :comment)";
                       ^---------------------------here
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out! gosh! really feel embarrassed overlooking that small error! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of :

```
`$query = "INSERT INTO `comments` (`id`, `post_id`, `comment`) VALUES (:id, post_id,:comment)";`
```

use:

```
`$query = "INSERT INTO `comments` (`id`, `post_id`, `comment`) VALUES (:id, :post_id,:comment)";`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NULL:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `comments` (`id`, `post_id`, `comment`) VALUES (NULL, :post_id,:comment)";
```

OR just leave it:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `comments` (`post_id`, `comment`) VALUES (:post_id,:comment)";
```

Then:

```
$check = $sql->execute(array(':post_id'=>$post_id,
                             ':comment'=>$comment));
```

Answer (score 0):

if your id is auto-increnmented dont send  values from php script

```
    function whatever($post_id, $comment) {

     $query = "INSERT INTO `comments` ( `post_id`, `comment`)    VALUES(:id,post_id,:comment)";
       $sql = $db->prepare($query);
   $check = $sql->execute(array(':post_id'=>$post_id,':comment'=>$comment));

  //verify if data is inserted
  if($check) {
  $test = 'inserted';
  } else {
   $test = $sql->errorCode();
 }
  return $test;
}
```